# Spring injects dependencies in constructor without @Autowired annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, autowired

I'm experimenting with examples from this official Spring [tutorials](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/) and there is a dependency on this code:
https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-async-method/tree/master/complete

If you look at the code on `AppRunner.java`  class, I have 2 questions:

1. When server is starting, if I put a breakpoint in this class's constructor, seems like in the constructor, the `GitHubLookupService` is provided by spring, using the `@Service` bean that was configured. BUT, there was no `@Autowired` annotation on the constructor, so how in the world this constructor get called with the right dependency?  It was supposed to be `null`.

Is it an automatic assumption of **Spring Boot**?
Does Spring see "private field + constructor argument, and it assumes it should look for an appropriate bean?
Is it **Spring Framework** or **Spring boot**?
Am I missing something?

2. As I remember, it was mendatory to provide *default constructor* to beans / service etc. How come this class (`AppRunner`) doesn't have a default constructor?
   How does Spring knows that it should run the constructor with the argument?
   Is it because it is the only constructor?

Answer (score 282, accepted):

Starting with Spring *4.3*, if a class, which is configured as a Spring bean, has only one constructor, the `@Autowired` annotation can be omitted and Spring will use that constructor and inject all necessary dependencies.

Regarding the *default constructor*: You either need the default constructor, a constructor with the `@Autowired` annotation when you have multiple constructors, or only one constructor in your class with or without the `@Autowired` annotation.

Read the [`@Autowired`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation) chapter from the official Spring documentation for more information.

Comment: Here the quote from the official documentation : 


_As of Spring Framework 4.3, an @Autowired annotation on such a constructor is **no longer necessary** if the target bean only defines one constructor to begin with. However, if several constructors are available, at least one must be annotated to teach the container which one to use._

Comment: In order for Spring to inject dependencies without using @Autoriwred, the field you declare needs to be declared as final.

Answer (score 26):

Think of it this way... Suppose you have the following component:

```
@Component 
public class FooService {
    public FooService(Bar bar) { /*whatever*/ }
}
```

When Spring is scanning this class, it wants to know how it should go about constructing an instance. It's using reflection so it can get a list of all of the constructors at runtime.

In this case, it is completely unambiguous how Spring must construct this instance. There's only one constructor so there is no decision to be made, and no ambiguity at all.

If you add `@Autowired` here, you are not narrowing anything down, and you are not giving Spring any extra information to help make its decision - its decision is already made because there is only one candidate.

And so, as a convenience, the Spring team decided `@Autowired` should be optional. Since its not helping the Spring framework to make a decision, its presence is just noise.

If your component has multiple constructors then you can use `@Autowired` on one of them to tell Spring "*use this one, not that one*".

Comment: 1+. we use some constructors for testing purposes only and we do not want them to be used for Spring injection, `@Autowired` on only one of them was the solution I found in this answer. thank you!