# REST webservice using spring boot and jersey. Error: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization

Tags: java, web-services, rest, maven, jersey

I'm following [this tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-building-restful-web-services-with-jersey) where I'm creating a REST web service in a Spring boot application with Jersey:

I'm getting an error in initialization. I cannot figure out what is it.

when I type in:

http://localhost:8080/rest/books

I get this error:

> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing
>   this as a fallback.
>
> Thu Apr 20 12:57:24 WAT 2017 There was an unexpected error
>   (type=Internal Server Error, status=500). Validation of the
>   application resource model has failed during application
>   initialization. [[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of
>   type public javax.ws.rs.core.Response
>   com.first.rest.test.controller.BookController.updateBook(java.lang.String,com.first.rest.test.model.Book)
>   at index 0.; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=PUT,
>   consumedTypes=[application/json], producedTypes=[], suspended=false,
>   suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS,
>   invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=class
>   com.first.rest.test.controller.BookController,
>   handlerConstructors=[org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.HandlerConstructor@642e8d2e]},
>   definitionMethod=public javax.ws.rs.core.Response
>   com.first.rest.test.controller.BookController.updateBook(java.lang.String,com.first.rest.test.model.Book),
>   parameters=[Parameter [type=class java.lang.String, source=oid,
>   defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class
>   com.first.rest.test.model.Book, source=null, defaultValue=null]],
>   responseType=class javax.ws.rs.core.Response}, nameBindings=[]}']

And in the console I have this

> ```
> 017-04-20 13:06:44.211 ERROR 1516 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.c.C.[.[.[.[.f.r.t.JerseyConfiguration] : Allocate exception for
> ```
>
> servlet com.first.rest.test.JerseyConfiguration
>
> ```
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during
> ```
>
> application initialization.
>       [[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public javax.ws.rs.core.Response

The project structure is:

[image: project structure Spring boot application]

Classes:
 Main App class:

```
   @SpringBootApplication
public class FirstRestApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FirstRestApplication.class, args);
    }
```

Jersey Config class:

```
@Configuration
@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class JerseyConfiguration extends ResourceConfig {
    public JerseyConfiguration() {

    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void setUp() {
        register(BookController.class);
        register(GenericExceptionMapper.class);
    }
}
```

Book Controller class:

```
 @Component
@Path("/books")
public class BookController {

    private BookService bookService;

    public BookController(BookService bookService) {
        this.bookService = bookService;
    }

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Collection<Book> getAllBooks() {
        return bookService.getAllBooks();
    }

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Path("/{oid}")
    public Book getBook(@PathParam("oid") String oid) {
        return bookService.getBook(oid);
    }

    @POST
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public Response addBook(Book book) {
        bookService.addBook(book);
        return Response.created(URI.create("/" + book.getOid())).build();
    }

    @PUT
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Path("/{oid}")
    public Response updateBook(@PathParam("oid") String oid, Book book) {
        bookService.updateBook(oid, book);
        return Response.noContent().build();
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("/{oid}")
    public Response deleteBook(@PathParam("oid") String oid) {
        bookService.deleteBook(oid);
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
```

Book model

```
public class Book {

    private String oid;
    private String name;
    private String author;
    private Category category;

    public Book() {

    }

     public Book(String oid, String name, String author, Category category) {
            super();
            this.oid = oid;
            this.name = name;
            this.author = author;
            this.category = category;
        }

        public String getOid() {
            return oid;
        }
        //more code

    }
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.first.rest.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>firstrest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>first rest</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: I see one problem,  but it is unrelated to the error. You need to `@Autowired` or `@Inject` the constructor, if you want it to be injected. The error is saying the problem is the `updateBook` method; that the string parameter will not be able to be injected for requests. The only way I could see this happening is if the `@PathParam` annotation is not the `javax.ws.rs.PathParam`. I've seen people accidently import the `javax.websocket.server.PathParam`, but I don't see this dependency in your project.

Comment: I found that I used it accidently too! I will correct it and see. Thank you.

Comment: Also I was wrong about the first sentence. You don't need the `@Autowired`, according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41092751/spring-inject-in-constructor-without-autowire). Learn somehing new every day :-)

Comment: @peeskillet It works now that I used `code`@PathParam`code` provided by jax-rs. Someone has to pay attention when importing package! :) I lost a lot of time looking for the reason!