# Autowire class's dependencies in jUnit without manual construction

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

My Service class has several autowired objects (Stored Procedures, SPs). Rather than a MockBean when/then, one test actually requires me to autowire the SP dependency objects in full, to see which object is being returned.

I can't really construct the dependencies and wire them myself like [suggested in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426323/injecting-autowired-private-field-during-testing) (e.g. via `ReflectionTestUtils.setField(service, "myService", new SP());`). Unfortunately, for these Stored Proc objects, there's no easy constructor for you. They extend `org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure` where the only possible constructor is with an internal datasource, `public MySP(@Autowired DataSource dataSource) { .. }`.

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    StoredProc1 storedProc1;
    @Autowired
    StoredProc2 storedProc2;
    @Autowired
    StoredProc3 storedProc3;

    // NEED TO UNIT-TEST THIS METHOD
    public StoredProc getStoredProc(Params params) {
        // ...
        // returns one of the 3 autowired objects
    }

    public mainServiceMethod(Params params) {
        // Interface implemented by all autowired StoredProc objects
        StoredProc storedProc = getStoredProc(params);
        // ...
        storedProc.someAction();
    }
}
```

In this example I need to jUnit `getStoredProc` which returns one of my normally-autowired objects, and see what's being returned (it's like a factory method). But all these objects are NULL during the course of testing, and I can't construct them myself due to the lack of a user-invokable constructor. So I need the full autowired hierarchy to be available for this test. How do I achieve this?

jUnit:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class MyServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    MyService myService; // actual service is autowired

    // Tried also autowiring the SP Dependencies, but they are NULL
     
}
```

Comment: Can't you use three `@MockBean`s?

Comment: Solved, see my answer.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I found the solution. I can `@Autowire` the Dependency Objects, which will construct them through the Spring configuration with no problem, and then the Service object can be `@InjectMocks` on which I will set those fields manually with `ReflectionUtils.setField(..)`.

Code:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class MyServiceTest {
    
     @InjectMocks
     MyService myService; // this will allow us to set Autowired dependencies via setField()

     @Autowired
     StoredProc1 sp1;  // Autowire to enable auto Spring construction
     @Autowired
     StoredProc2 sp2;  // Autowire to enable auto Spring construction
     @Autowired
     StoredProc3 sp3;  // Autowire to enable auto Spring construction

     @Test
     public StoredProc testGetStoredProc(Params p) {

        // Set fields on InjectMocks-enabled Service object
        ReflectionUtils.setField(myService, "sp1", sp1);
        ReflectionUtils.setField(myService, "sp2", sp2);
        // etc.
        // ...            

     }

}
```

Voila!

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Why do you not use the `MyService` bean as well if you are constructing real instances? Why `@InjectMocks` (you don't have any mocks) and not `@Autowired` (everything will be wired and injected correctly)?

Comment: It makes perfect sense and everything is wired correctly. As I said, I need the SP objects to be autowired by Spring, and the method I'm testing is one which returns a particular SP object based on parameters (like a factory). In order for me to test it, I can have an InjectMocks Service class where I populate these dependencies so they're available and not NULL (which otherwise they would be), as in a regular app.

Comment: Please explain why `@Autowired MyService myService` would not work in your case?

Comment: When I do `@Autowired MyService myService` in the jUnit, the SP dependencies in the Service object (`SP1`,`SP2` etc.) are NULL. You can try it yourself. Only the current layer (Service) is autowired, while its dependencies are not.

Comment: I tried myself and it works: all dependencies are correctly picked up by the component scan, added to the application context and then autowired. Since you haven't shared a [mre], I cannot try _your_ code. But it works for a regular Spring Boot application with a test.